# in-app-purchase updating application

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios4

i updated one of my in-app-purchase apps that was uploaded to the store , (music album application), when the update app is uploaded, and the user re-install it, the purchased contents in the older application will be lost, the user must download these contents again but free, how to keep the downloaded contents and save them in any update?
appreciate ur help guys
here's some code i used

```
NSArray *myPathList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *myPath = [myPathList objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* storagePath = [myPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"purchasedAlbums.plist"];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to include them in backups you have to save them in the `NSDocumentsDirectory` instead of `NSCachesDirectory`.
However, this is most likely against Apples storage guidelines. Apple started to enforce these rules recently. People start to use iCloud-Backups and every file inside the documents directory will be uploaded to apples server. To keep data transfers at a minimum you are only allowed to store real user data in the documents directory. When I say real user data I mean data that was created by the user. Stuff you can download or recreate by some computing must not be stored in the documents directory.

And if a user really reinstalls your app (not restoring from an backup) there is no way to restore downloaded files. Once the app is deleted all files that belong to the app are deleted too.